# What is the max line limit for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to know that what is the maximum line limit to display text into UITextView. If the content is more than the max line number into UITextview that what is the alternative of UITextview to display text.

Comment: the limit is your device's memory.

Comment: try your self, set line 1000 in attribute and check weather it is working or not, in my case text dose not display

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not display"?

Comment: I used simple way self.descTxt.text = String(val!) but I have large amount of text

Comment: UITextView gose blank

Comment: While using large amount of content to UITextView and frequently appending new lines of data, memory issues are experienced, and while scrolling cpu usage is also increased considerably. Instead tableview can be used, if separating text using "\n" and using that array as datasource work for your requirement.

Comment: that way is better but there is fucntionality for increase or decrease text size by the user so at there tableview is not usefull

Answer (score -1):

There is no real limit, it could be infinite but eventually you'd run into memory issues and your app would end up crashing.

> If the content is more than the max line number into UITextview that
>   what is the alternative of UITextview to display text.

This condition will never be true if you set the line number to 0. You can write as many lines as you want. If you want your `UITextView` to scale with your view make sure to set the proper constraints.

Answer (score -2):

In iOS , for UITextView control , there is no limit data.

```
- But while sending to server , based GET and POST Method , it may be differ.
- Based on the server, For GET method , there is a limit data but POST Method, there is no limit.
```